# HttpResponse body is empty even on successful request

Tags: http, httpresponse

I am doing a Http request to a web service and I get status 200 success. However when I try to read the response body (response.getBody()) it comes as empty.

When I do response.toString() I get System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
When I do response.getBodyAsBlob() I get null. Basically I am not able to read the response body even when the request is a success.

However when I copy and past the request endpoint in the browser or [Hurl.it](http://hurl.it) it gives back the expected JSON response.

Any idea on why I am not able to read the response body?

------------------- Update, the code --------------------------------

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('api_token', apitoken);
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: just updated with code.

Comment: Have you tried response.getBody()

Comment: Yes, its coming as empty.

Comment: did you check if the web service is sending back response correctly in body? To be double sure, I used same code above with a different endpoint "http://www.telize.com/jsonip" and I get the value in "response.getBody()"

Comment: api token is something the web service needs to authenticate the connecting user. But I cannot share it here.

Comment: may be i am wrong (or) unaware AFAIK there is access, refresh, ID token never heard of api_token header in salesforce

Comment: I am connecting to a web service which has its own headers. Many web services have their own headers that they use for authentication.

Comment: If the endpoint is a custom webservice are you very sure it is well written and has a body set, because getting a 200 with plain body seems something unheard of (atleast I haven't)

Comment: The thing is when I do the same thing with Hurl.it it gives me the JSON data. I don't know why it works there and not in my class.

Comment: Is the JSON data exceptionally large? What version of Salesforce is your class in? Have you tried putting a Content-Type header in your request? If not, just add `req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');` or something before you send the request.

Comment: If ti works with one web service and not another, seems the issue is with the other web service or the requirements for such web service. Without more information I am afraid there is not much else we can do to help. Especially since you said your code works on another endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after analyzing the request sent by the browser and Hurl.it it seems that I was missing a header called Accept-Encoding whose value was 'gzip'.

```
req.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
```

Now it is returning the JSON response it was suppose to.